# How to do a two way synchronization of user credential (Microsoft AD B2C) with a proprietary database

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

- We need to see the feasibility of synchronization of user credentials
  between the Microsoft AD B2C and proprietary database in real time.
- If it is feasible do you have any pointers on 'how to'.
- What is the hashing algorithm used in the  MS AD B2C credentials? is
  there a ay to customize it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a REST API call during the Sign Up and Password Reset authentication journey's to send the captured password claim to your API. Your API can then update your DB to keep it in sync.

You can call your REST API and can send any claims captured in the journey using this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-exchange?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

In this case, since you are looking to send a password, you must call your REST API as part of a [validation technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/validation-technical-profile), instead of directly as an orchestration step.

**You can send the plaintext password to your API.**

Here is an outline of what you need to configure:

In the sign up technical profile, add a call to your REST API as a validation technical profile.

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
...
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-SyncPasswordToDB" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Create the REST API technical profile to send the password to your endpoint:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-SyncPasswordToDB">
  <DisplayName>REST API call to communicate with Legacy DB</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://myApi.com/api/syncPassword</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
    <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">True</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="email" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" />
  </InputClaims>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```